# Asp.net page crashes other asp pages

Tags: asp.net, session, new-operator, page-directives

I have a couple Asp.net pages that use a few database connections - the problem is when these two pages are separately loaded they crash all the other .asp pages but none of the .aspx pages.

I get this error however for the asp pages that don't load: HTTP/1.1 New Session Failed

Comment: can you post some sample code so we can get an idea of what is happening on those pages?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that I found:

"This can have something to do with the permissions of the anonymous user account (IUSR) — see KB #210842. You can also try unloading the application and reloading it, changing the memory settings (e.g. isolated vs. shared) or application pool, and finally rebooting the box."

Reference: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-non-database-related-80004005-errors.html

Could you run the aspx pages in a separate application pool from the asp pages?  How much memory is available after running the aspx pages?

Comment: Yea John You're on to it because lately to fix the problem I recycle the one app pool that web site is in. I'm going to split them up and see what happens.